# Debian packaging - config files get overwritten on update

Tags: debian, deb

I found that in the packaging of ralph ng there seems to be an issue with Debian packaging. The desired behaviour would be that on first install a Debian menu prompt appears, to configure some database settings, on update those generated files should be left alone. Unfortunately the current behaviour is that the config files get overwritten on update.

Maybe anyone with packaging experience could [have a quick look](https://github.com/allegro/ralph/tree/ng/debian) and point me in the right direction to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

The “right direction” involves giving due consideration to all the advice in [the `debconf-devel` manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/debconf-devel.7), in particular [the “Config file handling” section](https://manpages.debian.org/debconf-devel.7#Config_file_handling) which gives a detailed example of handling this exact situation:

- the `config` script needs to read the existing configuration file, if any;
- the `postinst` script needs to handle missing entries in the configuration file, if any.

It would perhaps be better to use [`dbconfig-common`](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/dbconfig-common/) in this case; that deals with configuring database connections and a variety of other related database-handling tasks.

The `postinst` should also be fixed to avoid writing to standard output, since that can confuse `debconf`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'll check out your links and see if I'm able to fix it from here on by myself.